# Webgl unwanted mixtures of textures

Tags: javascript, 3d, glsl, webgl, textures

I'm rendering 2 planes with 2 mixed textures in each plane. But when I null one texture is like the GPU replaces the absent texture with other app texture, even with a texture of the previous plane.
I programmed a solution within the shader, consisting in detect if the *sampler2D textureN* has been initied:

```
void main()
{
    vec4 finalPx = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    if(has_tex_1 > 0.0)
    {
        finalPx += texture2D(tex_1, uv_1) * 0.5;
    }
    if(has_tex_2 > 0.0)
    {
        finalPx += texture2D(tex_2, uv_2) * 0.5;
    }
    gl_FragColor = finalPx;
}
```

... but I fear my solution could make it difficult the shader programming for me later and I think webgl should take in charge to make respect the code logic: if the app is not loading a texture the shader should load nothing.

This is my app:

```
const PICTURES = {
    indices: [
        0, 1, 2, 
        0, 3, 1, 
    ],
    vertices: [
        1.000000, -1.000000, 0.000000, 
        -1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 
        -1.000000, -1.000000, 0.000000, 
        1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 
    ],
    uv_layers: {
        'uv_1': [
            1.000000, 1.077309, 
            0.000000, -0.077309, 
            0.000000, 1.077309, 
            1.000000, -0.077309, 
        ],
        'uv_2': [
            1.500000, 1.500000, 
            -0.500000, -0.500000, 
            -0.500000, 1.500000, 
            1.500000, -0.500000, 
        ],
    },
};

const   vertexShaderCode = `
    precision mediump float;

    attribute vec4  vertex;
    attribute vec2  uv;
    varying vec2        UV;
    attribute vec2  uv2;
    varying vec2        UV2;

    uniform mat4 projectionMatrix, viewMatrix, modelMatrix;

    void main()
    {
        UV = uv;
        UV2 = uv2;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vertex;
    }`;

const fragmentShaderCode = `
    precision mediump float;

    varying vec2 UV;
    varying vec2 UV2;

    uniform sampler2D bitmap_1;
    uniform sampler2D bitmap_2;

    void main() {
        // Mix the bitmaps in equal proportions
        vec4 px1 = texture2D(bitmap_1, UV) * 0.5;
        vec4 px2 = texture2D(bitmap_2, UV2) * 0.5;
        gl_FragColor = px1 + px2;
    }`;

function loadShader(gl, vertexShaderCode, fragmentShaderCode) {
    
    const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderCode);
    gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        alert('An error occurred compiling the shaders: ' + gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
        gl.deleteShader(vertexShader);
        return null;
    }

    const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderCode);
    gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
        alert('An error occurred compiling the shaders: ' + gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
        gl.deleteShader(fragmentShader);
        return null;
    }
    return [vertexShader, fragmentShader];
}

function loadTexture(gl, url) {

    function isPowerOf2(value){ return (value & (value - 1)) == 0; }

    const texture = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    // Because images have to be download over the internet they might take a moment until they are ready.
    // Until then put a single pixel in the texture so we can use it immediately.
    // When the image has finished downloading we'll update the texture with the contents of the image.
    const level                 = 0;
    const internalFormat= gl.RGBA;
    const width                 = 1;
    const height                = 1;
    const border                = 0;
    const srcFormat         = gl.RGBA;
    const srcType               = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
    const pixel                 = new Uint8Array([1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]);  // magenta to warn if there is no texture
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat, width, height, border, srcFormat, srcType, pixel);

    const image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat, srcFormat, srcType, image);

        // WebGL1 has different requirements for power of 2 images vs non power of 2 images so check if the image is a
        // power of 2 in both dimensions.
        if (isPowerOf2(image.width) && isPowerOf2(image.height)) {
            // Yes, it's a power of 2. Generate mips.
            gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
        } else {
            // No, it's not a power of 2. Turn of mips and set wrapping to clamp to edge
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
        }
    };
    image.src = url;

    return texture;
}

function Material(gl, shaders) {

    this.shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(this.shaderProgram, shaders[0]); // Vertex shader
    gl.attachShader(this.shaderProgram, shaders[1]); // Fragment shader
    gl.linkProgram(this.shaderProgram);
    if (!gl.getProgramParameter(this.shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
        alert('Unable to initialize the shader program: ' + gl.getProgramInfoLog(this.shaderProgram));
        return null;
    }
}

function main() {

    var surface = document.getElementById('glcanvas');
    var gl = surface.getContext('webgl');

    if (!gl) {
        alert('Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser or machine may not support it.');
        return;
    }

    // One material for two textures maped within its own uv maps, like any 3D software could allow
    let shaders = loadShader(gl,vertexShaderCode, fragmentShaderCode);

    // -------------------------------------mesh 1---------------------------------------

    // Create the index buffer
    const indexBuffer_1 = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer_1);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(PICTURES.indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // The vertex buffer
    const vertexBuffer_1 = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer_1);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(PICTURES.vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // uv layers buffers (two uv channels for two different bitmaps)
    const uvBuffer_1_A = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer_1_A);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(PICTURES.uv_layers['uv_1']), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    const uvBuffer_1_B = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer_1_B);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(PICTURES.uv_layers['uv_2']), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    const material_1 = new Material(gl, shaders);

    // Create the textures for the respectives uv buffers
    const texture_1 = loadTexture(gl, TEXTURES_FOLDER+'old_fashioned_portrait_1.jpg');
    const texture_2 = loadTexture(gl, TEXTURES_FOLDER+'demon.jpg');

    // Transform data
    let modelMatrix_1 = mat4.create();
    mat4.translate(modelMatrix_1, modelMatrix_1, [-1.5, 0.0, 0.0]);

    let meshData_1 = {
        indices         : PICTURES.indices,
        indexBuffer : indexBuffer_1,
        vertexBuffer: vertexBuffer_1,
        uvBuffer_A  : uvBuffer_1_A,
        uvBuffer_B  : uvBuffer_1_B,
        material        : material_1,
        texture_A       : texture_1,
        texture_B       : texture_2,
        modelMatrix : modelMatrix_1,
    };

    // -------------------------------------mesh 2---------------------------------------

    // Create the index buffer
    const indexBuffer_2 = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer_2);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(PICTURES.indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // The vertex buffer
    const vertexBuffer_2 = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer_2);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(PICTURES.vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // uv layers buffers (two uv channels for two different bitmaps)
    const uvBuffer_2_A = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer_2_A);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(PICTURES.uv_layers['uv_1']), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    const uvBuffer_2_B = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, uvBuffer_2_B);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(PICTURES.uv_layers['uv_2']), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    const material_2 = new Material(gl, shaders);

    const texture_3 = loadTexture(gl, TEXTURES_FOLDER+'old_fashioned_portrait_2.jpg');
    const texture_4 = loadTexture(gl, TEXTURES_FOLDER+'phantom_girl.jpg');

    // Transform data
    let modelMatrix_2 = mat4.create();
    mat4.translate(modelMatrix_2, modelMatrix_2, [1.5, 0.0, 0.0]);

    let meshData_2 = {
        indices         : PICTURES.indices,
        indexBuffer : indexBuffer_2,
        vertexBuffer: vertexBuffer_2,
        uvBuffer_A  : uvBuffer_2_A,
        uvBuffer_B  : uvBuffer_2_B,
        material        : material_2,
        texture_A       : texture_3,
        texture_B       : texture_4,
        modelMatrix : modelMatrix_2,
    };

    // Render data and methods
    requestAnimationFrame(function () {render(gl, meshData_1, meshData_2, Date.now()*0.001);});
}

function render(gl, meshData_1, meshData_2, before)
{
    var now = Date.now()*0.001;
    var delta = now-before;
    rotation += delta;

    // ------------------------------------canvas----------------------------------------

    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    gl.clearDepth(1.0);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    const aspect            = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
    const fieldOfView   = 45 * Math.PI / 180;
    const zNear             = 0.1;
    const zFar              = 100.0;

    let projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
    mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix, fieldOfView, aspect, zNear, zFar);

    let viewMatrix  = mat4.create();
    mat4.translate(viewMatrix, viewMatrix, [0.0, 0.0, -5.0]);


    // -------------------------------------mesh 1---------------------------------------

    gl.useProgram(meshData_1.material.shaderProgram);

    // Vertices transformations
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(meshData_1.material.shaderProgram, 'projectionMatrix'), false, projectionMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(meshData_1.material.shaderProgram, 'viewMatrix'), false, viewMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(meshData_1.material.shaderProgram, 'modelMatrix'), false, meshData_1.modelMatrix);

    // Give the GPU the order of the points to form the triangles
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, meshData_1.indexBuffer);

    // Give the GPU the transformed vertices
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, meshData_1.vertexBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData_1.material.shaderProgram, 'vertex'), 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData_1.material.shaderProgram, 'vertex'));

    // First texture mapped in the triangles with the first uv coordinates
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, meshData_1.uvBuffer_A);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData_1.material.shaderProgram, 'uv'), 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData_1.material.shaderProgram, 'uv'));
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, meshData_1.texture_A);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(meshData_1.material.shaderProgram, 'bitmap_1'), 0);

    // Second texture mapped in the triangles with the second uv coordinates
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, meshData_1.uvBuffer_B);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData_1.material.shaderProgram, 'uv2'), 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData_1.material.shaderProgram, 'uv2'));
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, meshData_1.texture_B);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(meshData_1.material.shaderProgram, 'bitmap_2'), 1);

    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, meshData_1.indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    gl.useProgram(null);


    // -------------------------------------mesh 2---------------------------------------

    gl.useProgram(meshData_2.material.shaderProgram);

    // Vertices transformations
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(meshData_2.material.shaderProgram, 'projectionMatrix'), false, projectionMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(meshData_2.material.shaderProgram, 'viewMatrix'), false, viewMatrix);
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(gl.getUniformLocation(meshData_2.material.shaderProgram, 'modelMatrix'), false, meshData_2.modelMatrix);

    // Give the GPU the order of the points to form the triangles
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, meshData_2.indexBuffer);

    // Give the GPU the transformed vertices
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, meshData_2.vertexBuffer);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData_2.material.shaderProgram, 'vertex'), 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData_2.material.shaderProgram, 'vertex'));

    // First texture mapped in the triangles with the first uv coordinates
```

**I point out the problem before going on with the code:**

If I comment the next texture render is like the app (the GPU?) feeds the variable 'uniform sampler2D bitmap_1' with the first texture of the previous plane: 'old_fashioned_portrait_1.jpg'

```
    /*
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, meshData_2.uvBuffer_A);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData_2.material.shaderProgram, 'uv'), 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData_2.material.shaderProgram, 'uv'));
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, meshData_2.texture_A);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(meshData_2.material.shaderProgram, 'bitmap_1'), 0);
    */

    // Second texture mapped in the triangles with the second uv coordinates
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, meshData_2.uvBuffer_B);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData_2.material.shaderProgram, 'uv2'), 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.getAttribLocation(meshData_2.material.shaderProgram, 'uv2'));
    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, meshData_2.texture_B);
    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(meshData_2.material.shaderProgram, 'bitmap_2'), 1);

    gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, meshData_2.indices.length, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    gl.useProgram(null);

    requestAnimationFrame(function(){render(gl, meshData_1, meshData_2, now);});
}

main();
```

Answer (score 1):

What LJ said about WebGL being a state machine, or rather [it has a bunch of state that stays the same until you set something different](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/resources/webgl-state-diagram.html) is true but I want to add a few things

1. It's arguably considered best practice not to branch in a shader if possible.

   If you need a shader to do one thing or another make 2 shaders, one shader that does the one thing and a different shader that does the other. Engines like Unreal and Unity generate 1000s of shader variations. Even three.js generates lots of shader variations.
2. Branching and texture lookup with varyings [will break](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Non-uniform_flow_control).

   The important part of that link is this

   > If the texture associated with someOtherSampler uses mipmapping or anisotropic filtering of any kind, then any texture function that requires implicit derivatives in a fragment shader **will retrieve undefined results outside of uniform control flow**. ...
   >
   > Note: The GLSL compiler will not give you an error for this. It is perfectly legal GLSL code, and it only produces undefined behavior based on the texture and sampler objects associated with someOtherSampler.

   In other words this code

   ```
    vec4 finalPx = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    if(has_tex_1 > 0.0)
    {
        finalPx += texture2D(tex_1, uv_1) * 0.5;
    }
    if(has_tex_2 > 0.0)
    {
        finalPx += texture2D(tex_2, uv_2) * 0.5;
    }
   ```

   really needs to be this

   ```
    vec4 finalPx = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    vec4 color1 = texture2D(tex_1, uv_1) * 0.5;
    vec4 color2 = texture2D(tex_2, uv_2) * 0.5;
    if(has_tex_1 > 0.0)
    {
        finalPx += color1;
    }
    if(has_tex_2 > 0.0)
    {
        finalPx += color2;
    }
   ```

   make the parts that look things up from textures based on varyings (uv_1 and uv_2) not be conditional.
3. you can often design a shader so that it can be used without branching.

   In your example you could do this

   ```
    vec4 finalPx = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    finalPx += texture2D(tex_1, uv_1) * 0.5;
    finalPx += texture2D(tex_2, uv_2) * 0.5;
   ```

   Then just make a single pixel black texture like this

   ```
   const blackTexture = gl.createTexture();
   gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, blackTexture);
   gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                 new Uint8Array([0, 0, 0, 0]));
   ```

   Now when you only want to use one texture just bind `blackTexture` for the
   other texture. Because it's 0, 0, 0, 0 the math in your shader will add 0.0
   so it will have no effect. There's no more need for `has_tex_1` and `has_tex_2`.

   This is much also much better than relying the binding no texture which just
   happens to be 0,0,0,1 but will generate warnings in the browser.

Comment: If I correctly understand your answer, you might say that: the texture_N must have its own uv_buffer_N and its own shader attribute uv_N, always. But the problem is some 3D meshes dont use textures then their dont have uv coordinates. Taking that in account, the only solution I can see now is evaluate if the mesh has defined uv coordinates, and then send to GLSL a boolean-like variable to warn if the shader texture "slot" has been initiated.
You suggest me that I could create a black texture to replace "null textures" this means I'm forced to create uv coordinates for that texture, right?

Comment: My first suggestion is if you have a mesh that uses UV and another that doesn't you should make 2 shaders, a shader that uses UVs and a shader that doesn't. That is what a AAA game would likely do. This is also what three.js does. If you're set on making just one shader then, if your mesh has no UVs turn off that attribute, set the texture to a single white pixel (1,1,1,1). Your color math can be something like `color = diffuseColor * texture2D(tex, uvs)`; With a 1x1 pixel white texture it doesn't matter what UVs you'll always get 1,1,1,1 and 1,1,1,1 * diffuseColor = just diffuseColor

Answer (score 0):

WebGL is a state machine, every state you set remains until you set something different. If you want to unbind a texture you have to do so using:

```
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
```

Any read from an unbound texture unit will yield `vec4(0,0,0,1)`

Comment: You don't really want to render with no texture bound if your shader expects one. The browser has to do a bunch of validation and it will issue a warning that there is no texture bound to that unit. It's arguably better to attach some superfluous texture like a 1x1 pixel black or white texture, whichever fits your shader math better (0 or 1). In the example above a 0,0,0,0 1x1 pixel texture would appropriate.

Comment: I agree, it's also better for readability so one doesn't need to know the "default" value. This answer was aimed to show how to actually "null" a texture since that's what the OP originally intended on doing.